# How to create Configurable header and footer in plone?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Is there any way that I can create a Configurable footer and Header from  plone admin?

Header Configuration is for adding/edting menus for a website.

Footer Configuration is for adding/edting some url name.

Also I need to have a logo at top left and the logo is also editable from plone admin.

Comment: For the footer you may try https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.footer. It's using porltes to display informations in the footer section.

Answer (score 1):

In the header, the menu is autogenerated for you by Plone depending on the content, but you can turn this off by:

1. Go to http://localhost:8080/[yoursiteId]/portal_properties/site_properties/manage_workspace
2. Check the checkboxes to the right of both `disable_folder_sections` and `disable_nonfolderish_sections`
3. Hit 'Save' at the bottom

Now you can go to http://localhost:8080/[yoursiteId]/portal_actions/portal_tabs/manage_workspace and add more menu items (copy and paste the one that's already there if you like)

For the footer, take Mathias' suggestion above: https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.footer or perhaps [collective.doormat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.doormat) might suit you better - you'll have to experiment with that.

For the logo see [this page](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/change-the-logo.html) in the Plone docs. I can see that you might feel it should be easier, but this shouldn't be something you do every year (if your organization wants rebranding), right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the site-properties-way, to disable the non-content-area parts, wasn't aware of it, plus one of me.

Comment: @@Danimal:As you said I followed your steps  1. going to http://localhost:8080//portal_properties/site_properties/manage_workspace 2. checking the checkboxes to the right of both disable_folder_sections and disable_nonfolderish_sections 3. add hitting 'Save' at the bottom.   Unfortunately I get this error " raise BadRequest, 'Invalid or duplicate property id'"

Comment: That's surprising, which version of Plone are you using?  Is it a fresh install?

Comment: @@Danimal: I  m using plone4.3.4.1 and yes its a fresh install.

Comment: @Plonedoubts Danimal had used a tag-markup which swalloed the site-id, maybe that's the problem? It's not `localhost:8080//portal_properties/site_properties/`, but `localhost:8080/yourPloneSiteId/portal_properties/site_properties/`

Comment: @@Danimal: What you mean by "http://localhost:8080/mysite/portal_actions/portal_tabs/manage_workspace and add more menu items (copy and paste the one that's already there if you like)" .I can navigate to localhost:8080/mysite/portal_actions/portal_tabs there is no manage_workspace. Can you clearly tell me what you mean by "add more menu items (copy and paste the one that's already there if you like)"

Comment: @@Ida Ebkes: I accessed this localhost:8080/mysite/portal_properties/site_properties/ thats not the problem in my case.

Comment: Hm, hard to say what's going on, as this works in a freshly installed Plone-site, some of your customizations may be the cause. Could you please update your question with the used Plone-version?

Comment: Works also with 4.3.4.1 (we both omitted the last part of the URL `/manage_workspace`, but I guess, that's not the reason). For the portal_tabs: Danimal ment you can check the box at 'index_htm', click 'copy', click 'paste', then click on 'copy_of_index_html' and change the Title- and URL-values, according to what you want. FWIW, I'd recommend using ContentWellPortlets and assign a static-text-portlet above the content-area, after hiding the default menu-viewlets. Then you can edit your header just like a page and enter the links.

Comment: The error you get, might be solvable by doing "Clear and rebuild" in ""localhost:8080/yourPloneSiteId/portal_catalog/manage_workspace", as the docs suggest: http://docs.plone.org/manage/troubleshooting/exceptions.html#badrequest-the-id-xxx-is-invalid-it-is-already-in-use

Comment: @Danimal: I don't agree with your last sentence in the answer.  Changing the logo shouldn't involve any programming-skills, but be easy-as-a-pie, via the site's UI. Like in some other popular webpublishing-tools, and as in my proposed answer :-)

Comment: @IdaEbkes I didn't say it *shouldn't* be easier, only that it's not something you need to change every month.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I probably got the tone wrong, it's sometimes not easy when only relying on written words. May I ask you, if you can see any flaws in my proposed approach? It'll be appreciated as an important feedback of someone with a lot of Plone-experience :-)

Comment: @Danimal: And maybe it's worthwhile to mention, that the comment where you ask the OP for the Plone-version, wasn't visible to me immediately, but more than hour later, no idea why, gotta ask SO. Otherwise I'd probably let you have continue the conversation with the OP, before giving more cents.

Comment: @IdaEbkes no worries, glad you took over. I'm not begging to debug zope errors through SO comments! I'd only say that I preferred the start of my original answer

Comment: @Plonedoubts can I ask if you got it all solved? Otherwise Plone's IRC channel is easier means of debugging error messages like you have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a a way: Instead of relying on viewlets Plone ships with for the header- and footer-sections of a site, you can use portlets instead.

The addon "Products.ContentWellPortlets" will alow you to assign portlets also in top- and bottom-area, not only in left- and right-column.

For example, to add a logo, you can then assign a static-text-portlet, edit it just like a conventional page-type, insert a picture, it'll be also an ordinary image-item of the side, not a hard-to-customize ZMI-resource.

There is an addon, removing the viewlets and adding sample portlets in header and footer instead as a starting point (disclaimer: I'm the author): [adi.simplestructure](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adi.simplestructure). You can give it a try, if you're lazy ;)

Answer (score 0):

some other packages for editing your menuitems in the header:

- https://plone.org/products/collective.portaltabs
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quintagroup.plonetabs (more info on what this does in our setup: https://admin.kuleuven.be/icts/english/wms-en/extra/edit-header-links)

for our footer we use:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.phantasy (this allows layout adjustment through the web, more info on what this does in our setup: https://admin.kuleuven.be/icts/english/wms-en/extra/edit-layout)